# Sinatra/Ruby time zone troubles between development & production

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone, sinatra, datamapper

My Sinatra app is creating a simple object and persisting it to Postgres:

```
post '/' do
  event = Event.new(params)
  event.created_at = Time.now.utc
  event.date = next_date(params[:dayofweek], params[:time]) if params[:dayofweek] && params[:time]

  if event.save
    status 201
    event.to_json
  else
    json_status 400, event.errors.to_hash
  end

def next_date(dayofweek, hour)
  ...
  # some calculations that effectively culminate in the final line below
  ...
  my_time = Time.utc(2012, 11, 9, 12, 0, 0)   ## => 2012-11-09 12:00:00 UTC  
end
```

Object saves successfully. But when I retrieve the object from my `development` environment I get (json):

```
{ ..., "date":"2012-11-23T20:00:00-08:00" }   #notice the PST offset of -08:00.
```

I'm expecting the UTC time zone *or* `+00:00`. For some reason my development workstation, which is in PST, is factoring in its own time zone when saving to Postgres...at least that what it appears to be doing?!?

Sending the same code to the production server (Heroku) stores same data with proper offset of `+00:00`

How can I make my development workstation act like the production one? Or, **how should I be creating a proper UTC Date object in Sinatra?**

Comment: good answer below by @joelparkerhenderson, but don't forget to check the library you're using to connect to the database with (I'm assuming you're using AR or Sequel or something) as that can also have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, your comment has led me to what will likely be the solution, though I haven't tested it yet. I'm using **DataMapper** and after digging around on their site I found ["time properties will always be stored and retrieved in the timezone the datastore is set to"](http://datamapper.org/docs/misc.html) and a [link to a gem](https://github.com/hassox/dm-zone-types) that'll force a specific zone. *If you want to turn this into an answer I'll throw you the checkmark bone.*

Comment: So, after trying this gem it's, first of all, 2 years old!?! and doesn't appear to work... it sets the date to a somewhat non-ISO format `"2012-11-13 10:00:00 -0800"` and keeps the UTC offset as PST (-08:00). So, I don't know what to do!?! This is bizarre because I've always thought that ALL data should usually be persisted in UTC..but **DataMapper is intentionally making this difficult.** This is my first app using Sinatra. I must be doing something wrong?!? Should I switch to **ActiveRecord**?

Comment: I'll wait till it's fixed and I feel I've done something worth the checkmark first :) Try these two things 1) in Postgres, `SET timezone TO 'UTC'; select current_setting('timezone');` 2) set the TZ env variable to 'UTC', try `TZ=UTC ruby my_sinatra_app.rb` to see if that works, and if it does then set the env var in the rackup file or maybe the Sinatra configure block.

Comment: Yes, switch from DataMapper to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2):

First verify that your data does a round-trip successfully:

```
event.created_at = Time.now.utc
event.date = ...whatever...
tmp_created_at = event.created_at
tmp_date = event.date
event.save
event.reload!
tmp_created_at == event.created_at or raise "created_at failed"
tmp_date == event.date_at or raise "date failed"
```

Second, verify that the JSON is accurate.

- compare the JSON time string to the expected time
- the JSON time string has the -08:00
- is the JSON string the same actual time?
- For example, if you expect 10:00Z, does the JSON show 02:00-08:00 (i.e. the same actual time) or 10:00-08:00 (not the same actual time-- this is eight hours later).

If the data round-trip works, and the JSON is the same actual time, then look at whatever JSON library you're using to print the strings. Look for a method like "iso8601" that will print the time in standard UTC format.

Also, it may be helpful to know that Postgres saves timestamps without the time zone by default.

> "The SQL standard requires that writing just timestamp be equivalent to timestamp without time zone, and PostgreSQL honors that behavior. (Releases prior to 7.3 treated it as timestamp with time zone.) timestamptz is accepted as an abbreviation for timestamp with time zone; this is a PostgreSQL extension."

You can see this by describing the table, which may look something like this:

```
# \d events
Table "public.events"
Column     |            Type             |      Modifiers    
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------
id         | integer                     | not null default  
name       | character varying(255)      | 
created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
date       | timestamp with time zone    | not null
```

More info based on OP's feedback...

OP says: I'm using DataMapper and after digging around on their site I found "time properties will always be stored and retrieved in the timezone the datastore is set to" and a link to a gem that'll force a specific zone.

Because the round-trip shows a problem, try using a current version of the connection library e.g. a current DataMapper, and also try a current version of any similar library e.g. ActiveRecord (version 3.2.8 at the time of this writing).

Comment: Great info! Much appreciated. The round trip example code helped me prove that it was indeed failing but still doesn't tell me why. That, it turns out, appears to be a DataMapper "feature" (see comment on OP).